# SED/tr etc.. : How to comment out a line that contains "string" in a file?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, tr

my file contains lines such as these:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2002 -j ACCEPT
```

i want to comment out ( add # infront of ) the line that is

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2001 -j ACCEPT
```

how can i do this via SED or some other method via command line ?

should i seek for ..  e.g..

```
2001
```

and then comment out that whole line ( add # infront of )

or should i search for the entire line and then replace it with a new one that contains # ?

what would be the most practical method ? ( fastest )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Through sed,

```
sed '/ 2001 /s/^/#/' file
```

Add inline edit `-i` option to save the changes made.

```
sed -i '/ 2001 /s/^/#/' file
```

Example:

```
$ sed '/ 2001 /s/^/#/' file
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2000 -j ACCEPT
#-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2002 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` would do too.

```
awk '/2001/ {$0="#"$0}1' file
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2000 -j ACCEPT
#-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2002 -j ACCEPT
```