# pyspark show dataframe as table with horizontal scroll in ipython notebook

Tags: pandas, pyspark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-sql

a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` displays messy with `DataFrame.show()` - lines wrap instead of a scroll.

[image]

but displays with `pandas.DataFrame.head` 
[image]

I tried these options

```
import IPython
IPython.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
from IPython.display import display
```

but no luck. Although the scroll works when used within Atom editor with jupyter plugin:

[image]

Comment: Did you make any progress here?

Comment: I think this is what I did: limit few rows from spark dataframe, then on this "head" dataframe use `spark_df_head.toPandas()`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

this is a workaround

```
spark_df.limit(5).toPandas().head()
```

although, I do not know the computational burden of this query. I am thinking  `limit()` is not expensive. corrections welcome.

Comment: agreed that this is not a great solution - but I have not seen a "native" (non-pandas) alternative

Comment: Note that `limit()` do not keep the order of the dataframe.

Comment: @LouisYang If the DataFrame is sorted, yes it does.

Comment: this solution is good only for small tables. other then that is slows the all process

Comment: The performance seems not to be an issue,based on this single test:
Timing with the `%%timeit` magic:
`spark_df.limit(5).toPandas().head()` - *9.6s*
`spark_df.show(5)` - *10.1s*
Running on JupyterLab 1.0.1, connected to a remote databricks's PySpark with DBconnect. `spark_df` is a medium sized dataframe.

Comment: What if you don't have Pandas installed and it isn't an option?

Comment: display(spark_df) will show the records in tabular format.

to see all the columns / rows click on any one of the records, scroll bar will appear.

Answer (score 36):

Just add (and execute)

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
display(HTML("<style>pre { white-space: pre !important; }</style>"))
```

And you'll get the `df.show()` with the scrollbar
[image]

Comment: super nice, thanks!

Comment: This works great. Unfortunately it also has the drawback with adding horizontal scrolling to Markdown cells.

Comment: I wonder why this is not a default for spark/jupyter. are there any possible drawbacks?

Answer (score 16):

If anyone's still facing the issue, this could be resolved by tweaking website settings using developer tools.

When you do [image]

Open developer setting (<kbd>F12</kbd>). then inspect element (Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, Mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>). After this click (select) the dataframe output (shown in picture above). and uncheck whitespace attribute (see snapshot below)
[image]

You just need to do this setting once. (unless you refresh the page)

This will show you the exact data natively as is. No need to convert to pandas.

Comment: This was perfect for a quick and dirty demo, thank you!! yes it breaks if reload, but perfect for a screencast

Answer (score 10):

Just edit the css file and you are good to go.

1. Open the jupyter notebook `../site-packages/notebook/static/style/style.min.css` file.
2. Search for `white-space: pre-wrap;`, and remove it.
3. Save the file and restart jupyter-notebook.

Problem fixed. :)

Answer (score 2):

try `display(dataframe_name)` , it renders a scrollable table.

Comment: this did not work in Jupyter notebook for me. It works in Databricks notebooks, but the question is for Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Your answer has solved a very pertinent problem for me. I had been trying to download sample of data after performing some operations in Databricks and none of the answers on the internet seemed to work for me.  Your answer creates a table whose sample of 100 records I can download. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answers given above by @karan-singla and @vijay-jangir, a handy one-liner to comment out the `white-space: pre-wrap` styling can be done like so:

```
$ awk -i inplace '/pre-wrap/ {$0="/*"$0"*/"}1' $(dirname `python -c "import notebook as nb;print(nb.__file__)"`)/static/style/style.min.css
```

This translates as; use `awk` to update *inplace* lines that contain `pre-wrap` to be surrounded by `*/ -- */` i.e. comment out, on the file found in `styles.css` found in your working Python environment.

This, in theory, can then be used as an alias if one uses multiple environments, say with Anaconda.

REFs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884616/4521950
- [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk)

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://hugoworld.wordpress.com/2019/03/17/viewing-apache-spark-dataframes-in-jupyter-notebooks-ipython/) does not depend on pandas, it does not change the jupyter settings and it looks good (scrollbar will activate automatically).

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("My App").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True)

data = [
  [1, 1, 'A'],
  [2, 2, 'A'],
  [3, 3, 'A'],
  [4, 3, 'B'],
  [5, 4, 'B'],
  [6, 5, 'C'],
  [7, 6, 'C']]
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'))

# This will print a pretty table
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me since im using an environment i dont have access to css files and wanted to do it in a cell using jupyter magic commands got a neat solution.

Found the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476260/11795760

Just paste in a cell:

```
%%html
<style>
div.output_area pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

works also in scala notebooks

Answer (score 0):

To be precise for what someone said before.
In the file `anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- packages/notebook/static/style/style.min.css`
there are 2 `white-space: nowrap;` you have to comment the one here in this way `samp { /*white-space: nowrap;*/ }`
save it and the restart jupyter

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small function to convert PySpark Dataframe to Pandas Dataframe and then pick head and call it like this

Function

```
def display_df(df):
    return df.limit(5).toPandas().head()
```

Then call

```
display_df(spark_df)
```

You do have to have pandas imported

```
import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in its own cell:

```html
%%html
<style>
div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

This is based on the solution posted by @MateoB27 (their code did not work for me though it was close).

Answer (score -1):

I created below li'l function and it works fine:

```
def printDf(sprkDF): 
    newdf = sprkDF.toPandas()
    from IPython.display import display, HTML
    return HTML(newdf.to_html())
```

you can use it straight on your spark queries if you like, or on any spark data frame:

```
printDf(spark.sql('''
select * from employee
'''))
```

Comment: but `pyspark.sql.DataFrame().toPandas().head()` works just fine without needing your html  conversion (see question) ... and one wouldn't want to convert a big dataframe to pandas ... work around is to convert head to pandas