# Display pyspark Dataframe pretty

Tags: azure, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a jupyter notebook in azure. I have a dataframe in spark with hundreds of columns and rows. I want to display the dataframe pretty, like a table, which means I need a horizontal scrollbar. I tried the display function from

```
from IPython.display import display
```

but the df is still pressed in on page, just like text.

Comment: You might want to have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427138/pyspark-show-dataframe-as-table-with-horizontal-scroll-in-ipython-notebook It seems you can use an Atom editor plugin to do what you want to achieve, but it is just a workaround.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?