# How to show a dataframe in a good format in jupyter notebook using pyspark with apachee-toree kernel

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

It will become very difficult to read the output if it is not in the good formated manner like shown in the image in this link -> [required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9GY1.png). I am running my code on jupyter notebook in pyspark with apache-toree kernel.
Currently when i show my dataframe it looks somewhat like as shown in the image in this link -> [Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz7or.png).

I know there is a way using "magic" as mentioned on apache toree [website](https://toree.apache.org/) but it is also not working in pyspark. It works if i load a normal python notebook in jupyter. It gives the error shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhUH.png) with pyspark

I am not able to find anything on internet about this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark show dataframe as table with horizontal scroll in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427138/pyspark-show-dataframe-as-table-with-horizontal-scroll-in-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

I work around this problem by converting pyspark DataFrame to pandas DataFrame with toPandas method.