# How to disable line wrapping in Jupyter notebook output cells?

Tags: python-3.x, output, jupyter-notebook, word-wrap

By default longer lines of text in the output cells of a Jupyter notebook will be wrapped. How to stop this behaviour?

Comment: do you want a horizontal scroll bar or the output cell width's to adapt to its content?

Comment: both options would be acceptable. a horizontal scroll bar would be better.

Comment: For VS Code users, see [How can I prevent output lines from wrapping in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?](/q/61925283/11107541)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a simple CSS rule to the `custom/custom.css` file in my Jupyter user configuration:

```css
/*Disable code output line wrapping*/
div.output_area pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

The result:

[image]

The `div.output_area pre` selects the `pre` preformated text areas of the code output areas for the rule (set of css properties). The `white-space` property states how the browser should display white spaces in the selected HTML elements with the `pre` value the browser only breaks at new line characters `\n` and `<br>` elements.

This CSS renders well (with a fine horizontal scrollbar) for my Firefox v70.0 and Chorme v78.0.3904.97, according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=white-space%20pre) the `white-space: pre` property and value should work on all modern desktop browsers.

You can find out where your configuration resides by running the following shell command:

```
jupyter --config
```

If you want make further style modifications just play around with the inspector of your favorite browser on Jupyter Notebook tab. where you can modify the CSS without permanent effects.

## Update for JupyterLab

As kiesel commented: In JupyterLab the class of the parent div is changed to `jp-OutputArea-output`. However there is another problem: [Jupyter Lab does not read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58274140/1638350) the `custom/custom.css` file. There is two way around this.

### 1. (dirty, fast) edit the theme in use.

In my case I edited the `~/miniconda3/envs/< env name >/share/jupyter/lab/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-dark-extension/index.css` file and added the following code.

```css
div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {
    white-space: pre
}
```

of course this fix will only work in the one specific environment where you edited the theme index.css. Therefore I do not recommend it.

### 2. (clean, slow) Use an extension which supports custom CSS

This nice [fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367594/adam-wallner) made a [theme](https://github.com/wallneradam/jupyterlab-custom-css) for Jupyter Lab which allows you to include a custom CSS file.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: This still doesn't work for long numpy arrays. How could I solve that?

Comment: @JordanKohn Strange, for me numpy arrays are displayed already wrapped even with the default CSS and config. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65341534/10733210 this actually fixed my problem

Comment: This was so painful but I was having problems that something override this. apparently it's because of `log = logging.getLogger("rich")`, can't be sure though, just a note for future dev. In the end I output what I have and opened a new notebook to read whatever I needed.

Comment: For JupyterLab the div seems to be called `div.jp-OutputArea`

Comment: @kiesel thank you. It also does not read the custom.css file. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to mess around with a config file, you can modify the behaviour of a notebook ad hoc by calling the IPython.core.display function. Then add the CSS suggested by @atevm:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>div.output_area pre {white-space: pre;}</style>"))

for line in range(5):
    for num in range(70):
        print(f" {num}", end="")
    print()
```

Comment: This worked to stop the line wrap, but the cell displaying the data doesn't extend (can't scroll it side to see to actually SEE the unwrapped data :D )

Comment: @RightmireM I'm not seeing that issue. Side scroll works fine on my Mac in Chrome, at least.

Comment: Wish I could up arrow this response twice! Add that import and display line at the top of your jupyter notebook, and from there out you sparkdf.show(5,False) and it won't wrap!

Comment: To reenable wordwrap again: `display(HTML("<style>div.output_area pre {white-space: pre-wrap;}</style>"))`

Answer (score 10):

You can use an html magic command. Check the CSS selector is correct, by inspecting the output cell, then edit the below accordingly.

```
%%html
<style>
div.output_area pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment so I have to answer: maybe there's something different with the last versions of Jupyter. If the accepted answer doesn't work, you can try with "jp-OutputArea-output" instead of "div.output_area"; for example

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {white-space: pre;}</style>"))
```

And if you have a dark-mode browser and you don't like the resulting lighter scrollbars, you can try to set the dark mode in Jupyter adding

```
display(HTML("<style>:root {color-scheme: dark;}</style>"))
```

See: [How do I switch to Chromes dark scrollbar like GitHub does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940522/how-do-i-switch-to-chromes-dark-scrollbar-like-github-does)

Comment: Yes, this worked for me in JupyterLab Desktop 3.6.3 (though I used the magic html command, as other answers suggest, rather than HTML object)

Answer (score 1):

Printing DataFrames in Jupyter Notebooks may not display all columns if there are many columns:

```
print(my_dataframe.head(2))

                        open     high  ...             low_time            high_time
time                                   ...                                          
2015-02-06 00:00:00  0.77970  0.78590  ...  2015-02-06 00:30:00  2015-02-06 02:30:00
2015-02-06 04:00:00  0.78276  0.78433  ...  2015-02-06 04:30:00  2015-02-06 07:30:00
```

We can force Jupyter Notebooks to display all columns by setting max_columns option to None as shown below. However, **this will wrap the rows** adding a "\" if there are too many columns:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
print(my_dataframe.head(2))

                        open     high      low    close  tick_volume  spread  \
time                                                                           
2015-11-25 08:00:00  0.72714  0.72829  0.72525  0.72534        45192       1   
2015-11-25 12:00:00  0.72534  0.72615  0.72379  0.72429        48685       1   

                     real_volume             low_time            high_time  
time                                                                        
2015-11-25 08:00:00  87365088000  2015-11-25 11:30:00  2015-11-25 09:00:00  
2015-11-25 12:00:00  83349117000  2015-11-25 15:30:00  2015-11-25 12:30:00
```

This wrapping can be fixed by setting expand_frame_repr to false:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
print(my_dataframe.head(2))

                        open     high      low    close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume             low_time            high_time
time                                                                                                                               
2015-02-06 00:00:00  0.77970  0.78590  0.77933  0.78280        18061       4  21357500000  2015-02-06 00:30:00  2015-02-06 02:30:00
2015-02-06 04:00:00  0.78276  0.78433  0.78117  0.78401        12310       4  14275000000  2015-02-06 04:30:00  2015-02-06 07:30:00
```

In some cases the following may also help or be necessary:

```
pd.options.display.width=None
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this post did not work for me because I'm using Jupyter Lab (as noted by @kiesel). This slight change did the trick:

```html
%%html
<style>
div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

Comment: tagging with "JupyterLab" (source: https://jupyter.org/) so search on page finds this.