# jupyterlab 3 markdown style sheet

Tags: html, markdown, jupyter-lab

I am working on jupyterlab 3 and want to add e.g.

```
.boxed {
border: 2px solid black;
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and stuff like this to the style sheet.
I want to use the class inside a markdown cell in a notebook, that i open in jupyterlab 3 interface.
Is there a simple way or do i have do figure out writing a markdown extension?

Comment: Is this for the markdown file editor, notebook editor, or just for the JupyterLab UI? More details would help!

Comment: @krassowski it is for jupyter notebooks markdown cells, i have edited the quest. Thanks you for the comment, any help for this is appreciated, as i really would love to get rid of the copy and paste. I have wrote the style in a html magic, the problem then is that by opening one need to execute that first, so i really would like to implement that more persistent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom css file for Jupyter lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589502/how-to-create-custom-css-file-for-jupyter-lab)

Comment: The extension there suggest is not compatible with jupyterlab 3, see here: https://github.com/wallneradam/jupyterlab-custom-css/issues/5. And as i will publish in a jupyterhub, it was suggested to be not maintainable to directly change the `custom.css`, but thanks for the hint, if there will come jupyterlab 3 upgrade that would be great.