# How to have dark mode scrollbars?

Tags: css, scrollbar, mode

I want to get my scrollbar dark mode as well (exactly like Github does for example). Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66097469/9646947), using the css `color-scheme` works but as stated, it messes up the inputs and form-controls.

Is there a way to use this class but not let it override input and form-control? Or perhaps there are better ways to have dark scrollbars without defining a custom scrollbar from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a div which contains the scrollbar only and apply `color-scheme: dark;` style, or you could use `body::webkit-scrollbar` styling to create a custom scrollbar entirely, last I can think of is you could manually redefine the styling you do not want `color-scheme` to change.

Comment: Here's a doc on webkit-scrollbar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar