# How to disable iPython Notebook's (ipynb) cell output line wrapping in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use PySpark in VSCode `ipynb` documents. The text lines in the cells **output** are wrapped and it is not possible to understand them correctly.

[image]

For code cell <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keybinding toggles between wrapped and non-wrapped modes but it does not work for code output.

In Jupyter Notebooks (in the browser) this trick works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476260/4783029 But in VSCode it does not.

**Question:**
How to get unwrapped output in VSCode cell **output**?
Is there any option or keybinding?

Comment: This seems to involve the underlying architecture of jupyter. I checked the settings of jupyter and found no similar repair method. You can create problems in github and ask the developer for help. I created [anohter similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12705) to search for the way to modify css rule.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)