How numpy array full show in jupyter notebook without wrapping?
I already referred to 'How to print the full NumPy array without wrapping (in Jupyter Notebook)'.
However, my array size is 256x256.
Therefore, it is automatically wrapping in jupyter as below.

My array is based on image and only consisting of 0 and 1.
I just want to see my image shape with 0 and 1 such as below.
I also tried below code.
np.set_printoptions(threshold = np.inf)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth = np.inf)

 Reference for that post is here.

it works in my jupyter notebook with np.set_printoptions(linewidth=256*3, threshold=np.inf)
maybe some special configure in your jupyter?

Have you tried imshow? e.g. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.imshow(np.squeeze(image)) That can show even very large arrays.

There are also nice ways to print arrays that work with Jupyter because it supports MathJax/LaTex. See here, which links to numpyarray_to_latex and examples illustrating using that and related approaches here under 'Rendering Matrices' in 'Subject Matter Authoring Using Jupyter Notebooks;.

What is the bottom screenshot you just tacked on? First, just include links and not a screenshot that isn't clickable or searchable, or that allows StackOverflow's system to populate the side bars with related questions. You'll note in How do I ask a good question? it stresses 'DO NOT post images'. Your code is also a screenshot?!?! In fact it says, "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc."  under 'Help others reproduce the problem'. Second, it looks like it should go up around where you are using related approaches in your code.

I meant to include along with my links above, this code gist for 'Displaying an array as matrix in LaTeX in a Jupyter notebook'.

Two problems seem to mix here:

The line breaks introduced by Numpy:
You can fix these, as already commented and as you already tried, by
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf)


The line breaks (or rather, line wraps) introduced by Jupyter:
You can fix these, following this answer, by
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {white-space: pre;}</style>"))



Together, we have
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Avoid line breaks by Jupyter (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433850/7395592)
display(HTML("<style>div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {white-space: pre;}</style>"))
# Avoid premature line breaks by Numpy and show all array entries
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf, threshold=np.inf)
image = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
image

This, for me, produces the following output:

Alternatively, as you wrote that your image consists of 0s and 1s only (and thus exclusively of single-digit numbers): you can condense the output even more, by suppressing the commas and spaces, for example like so:
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML
# Avoid line breaks by Jupyter (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433850/7395592)
display(HTML("<style>div.jp-OutputArea-output pre {white-space: pre;}</style>"))
image = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
image_vals = "\n".join(f"[{''.join(str(val) for val in row)}]" for row in image)
print(image_vals)

Which produces the following output (note that I had to use print() in this case):

The only inconvenience that I could find in both cases is that a horizontal scrollbar only appears in the output cell if one scrolls to its very bottom (I tried with Firefox and Chrome).
