# Show completely DataFrame PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe and I'm using PySpark, when I'm showing the data, it not showing very well, like the next image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMovS.png)

How can I fix it? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a whole lot you can do. The issue is with line wrap. A common workaround is to use pandas

```py
df.limit(5).toPandas().head()
```

If you're using a Jupyter Notebook, you can read more choices here: [pyspark show dataframe as table with horizontal scroll in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427138/pyspark-show-dataframe-as-table-with-horizontal-scroll-in-ipython-notebook)