# Improve PySpark DataFrame.show output to fit Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

Using PySpark in a Jupyter notebook, the output of Spark's `DataFrame.show` is low-tech compared to how Pandas DataFrames are displayed. I thought "Well, it does the job", until I got this:

[image]

The output is not adjusted to the width of the notebook, so that the lines wrap in an ugly way. Is there a way to customize this? Even better, is there a way to get output Pandas-style (without converting to `pandas.DataFrame` obviously)?

Comment: you could just convert the first 5 rows to pandas df

Comment: `df.limit(5).toPandas()`

Comment: Two workarounds: Maybe you could try to expand your Jupyter Notebook cell like 
 the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-jupyter-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser or to use `df.show(vertical=True)` as you can see in the example at `def show(self, n=20, truncate=True, vertical=False)` in the source code https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py

Answer (score 28):

This is now [possible natively](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/dbb4d83829ec4b51d6e6d3a96f7a4e611d8827bc) as of Spark 2.4.0 by setting `spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled` to `True`:

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to work for me on my own dataset which has a lot of columns. `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled",True)` followed by 
   `df.limit(10)`

Comment: This would be good if it worked, which it does not on `2.4.3`, apparently.

Comment: This will load the entire dataset into your driver which may not be desired.

Comment: You may also configure this during session-creation: `spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True).getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 28):

After playing around with my table which has a lot of columns I decided the best thing to do to get a feel for the data is to use:

```
df.show(n=5, truncate=False, vertical=True)
```

This displays it vertically without truncation and is the cleanest viewing I can come up with.

Comment: The output from your code is kind of better than the horizontal view for me because it doesn't hide any columns.

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 10):

You can use an html magic command. Check the CSS selector is correct by inspecting the output cell. Then edit below accordingly and run it in a cell.

```
%%html
<style>
div.output_area pre {
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

Comment: genius! ---------

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SparkSession.builder, I recommend to set option `"spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled"` to `True`

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True).getOrCreate()
```

afterwards, to show the formatted table

```
df = spark.sql("select * from my_table")
df
```

you have to show the df like `df`, not `df.show()`

works with pyspark 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answers given above by @karan-singla and @vijay-jangir given in [pyspark show dataframe as table with horizontal scroll in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427138/pyspark-show-dataframe-as-table-with-horizontal-scroll-in-ipython-notebook/61867701#61867701), a handy one-liner to comment out the `white-space: pre-wrap` styling can be done like so:

```
$ awk -i inplace '/pre-wrap/ {$0="/*"$0"*/"}1' $(dirname `python -c "import notebook as nb;print(nb.__file__)"`)/static/style/style.min.css
```

This translates as; use `awk` to update *inplace* lines that contain `pre-wrap` to be surrounded by `*/ -- */` i.e. comment out, on the file found in `styles.css` found in your working Python environment.

This, in theory, can then be used as an alias if one uses multiple environments, say with Anaconda.

REFs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884616/4521950
- [Save modifications in place with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/save-modifications-in-place-with-awk)

Answer (score 1):

I can only attest to VS code's Jupyter output - but default behavior garbles/"word-wraps" spark dataframes the same way. At least in VS Code, one you can edit the notebook's default CSS using `HTML()` module from `IPython.core.display`

This command will override default Jupyter cell output style to prevent 'word-wrap' behavior for spark dataframes.

Just run this code snippet in a cell (in VS Code, it hot-fixes the issue even if you have the output already displayed).

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

HTML("""<style>
    .output-plaintext, .output-stream, .output{
        white-space: pre !important;
        font-family: Monaco; # Any monospaced font should work
    }</style>""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same answer as [the top-voted answer from three years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55484426/3025856), but with less explanation? The previous answer uses a couple of additional arguments, but the core guidance is the same.